# Base controller error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I want to run "HELLO" line but it only run "BYE" line.
(1 BaseController for many other controllers, reuse code)
help me, thanks

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        string str="HELLO";

        return View();            
    }
}


public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        string str="BYE";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: URL look like http://localhost/test/index to run

Comment: This is nothing to do with MVC, this is basic C#. I suggest you go read up on how inheritance and overriding works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        return base.Index();
    }
}
```